# Trying to understand an already made JApplet code

Tags: java, swing, graphics, actionlistener, japplet

**Question :**As you can see when we execute this code and click on Circle button it counts it properly, but when square button is clicked it again counts it properly but then once again circle button is click then the previous counts of circle gets disappeared and it again starts from 1.

**Where's the problem :** After doing a bit of search i came to know that the method **getGraphics()** invoked on ContentPane object is causing the problem, i tried changing it but then the program doesn't even run and if it runs then all GUI components will have problem.

Edit : Did what mKorbel said

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CountShapes1 extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    Container cont;
    JPanel p;

    JLabel lblCount;
    JButton btCircle,btSquare;

    boolean blnCircle,blnSquare;
    int count=0;
    String shape="";

    public void init() 
    {
        cont=getContentPane();

        lblCount=new JLabel("Shape Count : 0",JLabel.CENTER);
        lblCount.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,18));
        cont.add(lblCount,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        btCircle=new JButton("Circle");
        btSquare=new JButton("Square");

        btCircle.addActionListener(this);
        btSquare.addActionListener(this);

        p=new JPanel();
        p.add(btCircle);
        p.add(btSquare);

        cont.add(p,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
     {
        if(ae.getSource()==btCircle)
        {
            if(blnSquare==true)
            {
                blnSquare=false;
                count=0;
            }

            blnCircle=true;
            shape="CIRCLE";
            count++;

        lblCount.setText(shape+" Count : "+count);
        repaint();
    }

    if(ae.getSource()==btSquare)
    {
        if(blnCircle==true)
        {
                blnCircle=false;
                count=0;
        }
        blnSquare=true;
        shape="SQUARE";
        count++;

        lblCount.setText(shape+" Count : "+count);
        repaint();
    }
}

    public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
       cont.paint(cont.getGraphics());

       int x=10,y=30,w=30,h=30;
       if(shape.equals("CIRCLE") || shape.equals("SQUARE"))
       {
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
         {
            if(shape.equals("CIRCLE"))
            {
                g.drawOval(x,y,w,h);
            }
            else
            {
                g.drawRect(x,y,w,h);
            }
             x+=40;
                if(x>=getWidth()-30)
                {
                    x=10;
                    y+=40;
                }
         }  //for -loop finished

      }  // if-finished
   } // paint() finished
 } // class finished

/*
   <applet code="CountShapes1" width=500 height=500>
   </applet>
*/
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, reduced code (important issues) about describtions from your question

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a mistake on the previous developer to be calling `paint` on `cont`. This will be done automatically as part if the part process anyway, I'd replace it with `super.paint`

I suspect that the original author couldn't figure out how to get more then one shape to paint at a time.

The `paint` method is only ever going to be able to paint one shape at a time. Unless you're adding the shapes to some kind of list, which you then loop over, each time the `paint` method is called, each time `paint` is called, it will erase the previous content and only paint the named shape.

You really should create a custom component, extending form something like `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method. In this, you should the paint the shapes.

The problem you'll have with the current implementation, is its possible for the shapes to paint over the controls, which would most likely not be desirable

Comment: +1 :-) dont understand, nor question, maybe your are right :-)